# Need help to fix while loop and etc

Tags: python, while-loop

The code below returns the following:

```
list = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]

while len(list) >= 0:
    smallest_no = sorted(list)[0]
    second_smallest_no = sorted(list)[1]
    sum_smallest_nos = smallest_no + second_smallest_no

    list.remove(smallest_no)
    list.remove(second_smallest_no)
    list.append(sum_smallest_nos)

    print(list)
```

The output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 4]
[5, 6, 8]
[8, 11]
[19]
```

The error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d6ccc5cb5f76> in <module>()
      5 while len(list) >= 0:
      6     smallest_no = sorted(list)[0]
----> 7     second_smallest_no = sorted(list)[1]
      8     sum_smallest_nos = smallest_no + second_smallest_no
      9 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

1) Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

2) If I change it to return (list), I get SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

3) How can I get my code to return the sum of the appended values in the loop. In this case, 4 + 8 + 11 + 19.

Comment: In addition to the no no of removing from a list, you need to rename `list` to not shadow the built in list object

Comment: Actually, my dupe is incorrect. What is it you're trying to do ultimately?

Comment: this line is the problem :`smallest_no = sorted(list)[0]` your stop condition is list >=0 but you are accessing the [0] element of the list while `len(list) ==0`

Comment: When Your condition is `len(list) >= 0` you are actually **never** stops the while loop.
So, when you try to reach the list in index `1` when you are down to the last element in the list. you will get our of bound.

Comment: @OmerBenHaim is right. must be because of his SWAG

Comment: @Green he is living on the edge with a while loop instead of a for loop

Comment: I'm trying to do something like a binary search tree. First from the given list, take the 2 smallest numbers and sum them up, and keep doing this until the length of the list becomes 1.

Comment: @OmerBenHaim your stop condition is list >=0 but you are accessing the [0] element of the list while len(list) ==0. How can we resolve this?

Comment: I seem to have solved it but changing the while loop to for i in range(1, len(list)):

Comment: To implement @OmerBenHaim's fix, replace `while len(list) >= 0:` by `while len(list) >= 2:` (2 and not 1 because you also access `sorted(list)[1]`).